IS there a way to find out the Serial, firmware and OS version of a USB device?
I am using the kernel 5.15 based embedded device; have the requirement to figure out the unique field of a USB device, so that I can distinguish when the same vendor, model USB devices(VID,PID are same) connected. I am heavily depended on the Serial number of USB device, which will be unique between the USB devices of same type( same VID,PID).
Having said that, know that I can read the device and interface descriptor of the USB device with udev daemon. However some of the USB devices like printer and scanners are not showing serial number; it is empty.
Also I am interested to collect the firmware and OS version information if can find this with any of the other way as udevadm info way of collecting USB device attributes don't have field for firmware!.
Have found the util based on LINUX like usbview : https://github.com/gregkh/usbview it is a GUI way of giving the USB device descriptor atttibutes info. But there is an interesting tool in WIndows: USBDeview;
reference links
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html
https://www.majorgeeks.com/
This tool/util gives other details of USB device along with Firmware versions!
So the APIs for reading the firmware information are proprietary?
there is no other generic way to find out the Firmware and Serial number information of USB device?

There's no generic way to get a unique identifier for USB devices that i know of. If its for a specific type of device, you're just going to have to check what information you can get and see if anything is a unique identifier. You can do this with udevadm, lsusb, dmesg, ... or something similar.

@Silbee thanks for the reply. yeh I am setting for the same!. If serial number is available then it will be helpful to uniquely identify the USB device!. else use any available different attribute of device. There can't any generic ways as of now, as you said.
